# asp.net mvc invoke controller action from helper class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

As i understand asp.net mvc 2 allows use to invoke an action directly without mvc futures.
so instaed of:

```
<%Html.RenderAction
```

we can use:

```
 <%Html.Action
```

I'm using an Helper class to invoke the action but inside the helper class i cannot find the .Action attirbute:

```
    public static void CatalogList(this HtmlHelper helper, string text)
{
    helper.ac 
}
```

there is no Action, but it work inline in the aspx file:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Category</h2>
<%Html.Action( %>
```

not sure what i'm doing wrong, i really like the call to be in the helper and not inline.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a using directive for the right namespace: "`System.Web.Mvc.Html`".

`Html.RenderAction()` is included in asp.net mvc 2 as well. The only difference between `RenderAction()` and `Action()` is that `Action()` returns the rendered action as a string while `RenderAction()` renders the action directly to the output.